# How can I validate that the src of an image is set using Jquery Validator

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using Jquery Validator for Validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

I'd like to add a custom validator to ensure that an image has its src set.
I've added this custom validator when the document ready:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkImageSrc", function(value, element) {
                        // Check if the img src is not empty
                        return (element.attr('src').trim() !== '');
                    }, "Please provide a valid image source.");
```

I am executing the Validate method when a button is pressed:

```
$('#hunt-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                            ignore: 'not:hidden',
                            rules: {
                                the_name_of_element_with_lots_of_under_scores:{
                                    checkImageSrc: true
                                },
...
```

Validate however, is not validating the element.
if I update the checkImageSrc function to always return false, it still doesn't detect my element.

Things to Note: The 'the_name_of_element_with_lots_of_under_scores' element is originally hidden, and gets populated after cropper.js binds a cropped image to it

What is wrong with my code?